# How to access (and edit) data from a paused activity without using static or calling startActivity()/startActivityForResult

Tags: android, search, android-activity, argument-passing

I have implemented a search-function in my sourcecode which will be started when the user clicks the search-button on his device or the one in my actionbar. If he clicks the one on my actionbar I simply call `onSearchRequested`. Now here is my problem:

When the Search is done I display the results in a ListView. If the user clicks on an Item I want do go back to my `MainActivity` (which will always exist when the app isn't finished) and modify some values there und call a method of Main.

I know that there is `startActivityForResult` but I don't know how I could implement that because if the User hits the search button of his device the app automatically calls `onSearchRequested`... So the only solution that comes to my mind would be to implement a static method in my Main-Activity which I can call from within the Activity displaying my search results. But that isn't such a nice solution (or?)!

To summarize my question: is there an elegant way to get back from my activity displaying my search results to my main-activity and transfer data without `startActivityForResult` or implementing a static method in Main?

Thank u very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing `startActivityForResult` is pretty easy. [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) might help you.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Ah ok i forgot that I could simply overwrite "onSearchRequested" and implement startActivityForResult there... Is that what you meant?

Comment: I thought you have been already implemented `onSearchRequested`, and tried to find an example for using `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: I just implemented that the app calls onSearchRequested when the user hits the search-button of my actionbar in the same way as it is called when the user hits the search-button of his device. so I did not overwrite onSearchRequested and thus this method called "startSearch(null, false, null, false)". so I forgot that i could simply overwrite the method and implement there startActiviryForResult. that should work should'nt it?